# Domino Webservice provider - What's the maximum SOAP message size?

Tags: lotus-domino

How can I determine the maximum SOAP message size for a request to a Domino web service provider?

Thanks

Mario

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the "HTTP Protocol Limits" configured in the Server Document.
You can find these settings on tab "Internet Protocols...\HTTP"
Cheers, Klaus